# Facebook Fan Page Users (Likes List)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have been reading Facebook's API and several questions here @ Stack Overflow but i can't find an answer to my question.

I would like to get the name and id of every single user who has liked a specific fan page but when i get the "likes" i only get the Famous verified user's/companies pages that have liked this fan page before. Now my questions are:

1- If i have an admin token for this fan page and i run: "v2.7/"fanpageid"/likes" will i get all of the users? (Because with my token i only get public figures who have liked instead).

2- If the answer to the last question is "no" what's the best way to get the names and user id's of the people who have liked this page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a list of all fans. You would not be allowed to do anything with the user data anyway, just because they liked your page does not mean you can store their data or use it in any way.